# Example to illustrate difference between support and domain

Tags: probability

Assume that X is a discrete random variable, I understand that the domain of X is the set of values it can take and the support of X is the set of values it takes with non-zero probability. 
Can someone give me an example of where

1) $S \subset D$

2) $S = D$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable that takes on the value 1 when you are right, and 0 when you are wrong. Then domain equals support, since sometimes you are right, and sometimes you are wrong.

Let $Y$ be the random variable that takes on the value 1 when I am right, and 0 when I am wrong. Then the support is strictly contained in the domain, since I am never wrong.

Comment: But if you are never wrong, $P_Y(x=0) = 0$ and thus, by definition of support, it won't be in the support.

Comment: @Inquest: That’s exactly what Gerry is saying: it’s in the domain, but not in the support.

Comment: Oh. Super Smart Answer!